# Executing sf operations on grouped objects

Tags: r, gis, intersection, r-sf

I am trying to find intersecting `sfc_LINESTRING`s by group, where both intersecting `sfc_LINESTRING` objects are grouped. This question specifically relates to `st_intersects`, but I think the workflow will be the same for other operations within `sf`. Similar questions have been answered [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375010/iterate-st-intersection-sf-over-factor-levels) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281078/r-can-dplyrgroup-by-work-with-sfst-intersects), but in both cases only one of the intersecting objects was grouped and in any case I haven't been smart enough to make it work for my data set.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

line1 <- data.frame(lon = c(1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 2.0, 2.5),
                lat = c(1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 2.1, 2.6),
                grp = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C")
                ) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon","lat"), dim = "XY") %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise(do_union = FALSE) %>% 
  st_cast("LINESTRING") %>% 
  mutate(grp = c("A","A","B"))

line2 <- data.frame(lon = c(1.2, 1.3, 2.2, 2.3),
                lat = c(1, 1.5, 2, 2.5),
                grp = c("A", "A", "B", "B")
                ) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon","lat"), dim = "XY") %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise(do_union = FALSE) %>% 
  st_cast("LINESTRING")

plot(line1, lwd = 2, key.pos = 4, reset = FALSE)
plot(line2, lwd = 2, lty = 2, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

I would now like to find the intersecting `sfc_LINESTRING`s by the relevant group. Unfortunately, the simple solution I had hoped for using `group_by` throws an error:

```
int <- line1 %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  filter(lengths(st_intersects(line1, line2)) >0)
```

Using my actual data set, I can get it to run, but the `group_by` command seems to be ignored, so that I get all intersecting objects, not just those which match by group. To be specific, in this case the result should only select one `sfc_LINESTRING` for each group, i.e. matched continuous and dashed green line and matched continuous and dashed red line. The dashed red line should NOT create an intersection with the green line. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely sure if I understood your request correctly, but I am giving it a try! So, please find below one possible solution using the `st_join()` function of the `sf` library, and then some `dplyr` functions to get the final result.

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

results <- line1 %>% 
  st_join(., line2, join = st_intersects) %>% 
  filter(., grp.x == grp.y) %>% 
  rename(grp = grp.x) %>% 
  select(-grp.y)
```

- Output

```r
results
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 1 ymin: 1 xmax: 2.5 ymax: 2.6
#> CRS:           NA
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   grp           geometry
#>   <chr>     <LINESTRING>
#> 1 A       (1 1, 1.5 1.5)
#> 2 B     (2 2.1, 2.5 2.6)
```

- Visualization

```r
plot(results)
```

[image]

---

**PS:** In case you want to get the two intersecting lines in each group within the same `sf` object, you can extend the code as follows:

- Complementary code

```r
results2 <- results %>% 
  st_union(.,line2, by_feature = TRUE) %>% 
  filter(., grp == grp.1) %>% 
  select(-grp.1)
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all
#> geometries
```

- Output 2

```r
results2
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: MULTILINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 1 ymin: 1 xmax: 2.5 ymax: 2.6
#> CRS:           NA
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   grp                                                                   geometry
#>   <chr>                                                        <MULTILINESTRING>
#> 1 A     ((1 1, 1.25 1.25), (1.25 1.25, 1.5 1.5), (1.2 1, 1.25 1.25), (1.25 1.25~
#> 2 B     ((2 2.1, 2.275 2.375), (2.275 2.375, 2.5 2.6), (2.2 2, 2.275 2.375), (2~
```

- Visualization

```r
plot(results2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>